# Why array cannot be accessed like given below?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below code returns true. If that is the case why does 4th line in the code error out?

```
var x = ['a', 'e', 'f'];
x[2];
alert('2' in x);
alert(x.2);
```

Comment: I bet it's the same reason why you can't have something like `var 2nd = "second"`. Identifiers can't start with a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only property names you can access with the dot syntax are those that conform to JavaScript's rules for identifier names (first character is a letter, _, or $, and remaining characters are letters, numbers, _, or $).

What you have there is a syntax error, and that's why it errors out.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

> > Dot notation
> >     get = object.property;
> >     object.property = set;
> >     property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For example, object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.

You can use the square bracket notation to access a property with any name, so either of the following will return the item you want:

```
x[2];
x["2"];
```

Comment: function foo(a, b) {
    arguments[1] = 2;
    alert(arguments.length);
    }
    foo(1); why does it alert 1 and not 2. Its diff question!!!

Comment: @Joysamvedh If you have a different question, you should ask it as a different question, but the answer is that `arguments` is not an array, so it doesn't have all the behavior of an array.